# how to implement a circular counter?

Tags: c

I want to make a circular counter in C programming.
   First variable can store value from 0-3.
   Second variable asks the value from user (from 0-3).
   Third variable asks user to move either left or right

If third variable is left 
    the second variable should move left:

```
3->2
2->1
1->0
0->3
```

Similarly if third variable is right
    the second variable should move right:

```
0->1
1->2
2->3
3->0
```

Comment: Can you post your attempts to implement this ?

Comment: And explain what exact difficulty you have in reference to your attempt.

Comment: Counting up: `x = (x + 1) & 3`, counting down: `x = (x + 3) & 3`

Comment: Read about [arithmetic expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic) and about the modulo (`%`) operator.

Comment: i am able to move left and right by using modulus the problem occur at the edge .how can i move from 0 ->3 if third variable is left and 3->0 if third variable is right .Should i make a function to handle  these edge points or there can be other way .Actually the question is about direction North ,south,east west . i am using this to find the final direction if person move left or right from one direction

Comment: @Rotem thanks that worked :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yeah the issue was at the edge .

Comment: @Rotem That bitwise operation only work for multiples of two, not for the general case (like if the max value was `4` instead of `3`).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sure, it's a wisecrack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int max = 3, num, i;

    num = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", num);
        num = (num + 1) % (max + 1);
    }
    puts("--");
    num = max;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", num);
        num = (max - -num) % (max + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
--
3
2
1
0
3
2
1
0
3
2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap at a power of two, then this technique will work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int x : 2;    /* Holds up to 4 values */

} SmallInt;


int main()
{
    SmallInt up   = {0};
    SmallInt down = {0};

    for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", up.x, down.x);

        up.x++;
        down.x--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it eventually overflow though? Isn't x getting incremented up to one byte, despite wrapping around the values, or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @byteventurer No.  the integer in effect has 2 bits intead of 8, so no  it wraps from 3->0 and 0->3.

Comment: @hustmphrrr  i look at it as more entertainment, but it does come in handy sometimes.